# Why is the Sorting tab missing from CiviReport?

Tags: civireport, reports, custom-reports, sort-order, column

What configuration is required in order to display the "Sorting" tab in CiviReports? Is there a plugin for a Wordpress-based install to allow for column-based sorting?

Comment: Which report is this on?

Comment: another option might be SearchKit and Afform depending on what entity you are focussed on

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that no sorting fields are defined for the reports hence it doesn't appear to show.